# Can't deploy rails4 project with capistrano. rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am getting error while deploying my rails4 app to VPS. 
The error I'm getting is

```
rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed
```

But using "ruby -v" I get

```
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]
```

And in my gemfile I have

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

This error appears after bundle install recipe

```
2013-08-04 23:23:56 executing `bundle:install'
* executing "cd /home/yasinishyn/apps/kaiser/releases/20130804202355 && bundle install --gemfile /home/yasinishyn/apps/kaiser/releases/20130804202355/Gemfile --path /home/yasinishyn/apps/kaiser/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
[198.211.125.183] executing command
** [out :: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed
** [out :: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 
command finished in 355ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/yasinishyn/apps/kaiser/releases/20130804202355; true"
servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
command finished in 342ms
```

Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: can you post the output of `rbenv versions` (executed on the server)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you Benjamin, but the error was realy stupid )).
Localy I use ruby 2.0.0-p195 which was installed by rvm. On my server I user ruby 2.0.0-p0 which was installed by rbenv, because rbenv don't have ruby package 2.0.0-p195.

So while I was creating new rails4 app by rails-composer, I don't noticed that it was created with   ***.ruby-version*** file inside of which was a line with ruby version ***ruby 2.0.0-p195***, so I simply *** git rm .ruby-version***, and everything is working.

Answer (score 4):

That's most certainly a PATH problem, capistrano will send commands through ssh without opening a console session and the profile files are not loaded the same way if you open a  ssh console session. That may explain why through ssh console you can get a correct rbenv environment but not through capistrano.

**The following works with debian / ubuntu, and need to be adjusted for other distro**

I suppose you added some `export` instruction in one of your profile file. In ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc perhaps.

*The `export` instruction I use are the following, but they may be different in your configuration, so if rbenv is properly working when you open a ssh console then you can keep your set of `export` commands. The trick I'm going to detail is just to place them at the right place.*

My `export` instructions are:

```
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/opt/rbenv'
echo 'export PATH=/opt/rbenv/bin:$PATH'
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"'
```

1-

Remove them from any files where you previously included them and place them in the file /etc/profile.d/rbenv

2-

Edit the file /root/.bashrc (or /home/your_user/.bashrc if you do access your server with another user than "root") and add the line `source /etc/profile.d/rbenv` just before the line `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`

3-

Edit the file /home/deployer/.bashrc (assuming you are using "deployer" user for capistrano, otherwise adapt the path) and add the line
`source /etc/profile.d/rbenv`
just before the line `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`

4-

Verify it's working by opening another ssh console session and trying `ruby -v`. Then capistrano should work correctly

**Other possibility**

rbenv need rehash after you manually install gems, so run on your server `rbenv rehash` just to be sure

Comment: I have 5 other rails apps on that VPS, and problems appeared only with this one. I think it is because I use here rails4.

Comment: I am using `default_run_options[:pty] = true 
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` in my cap file and previously I have added permission like this `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh yasinishyn@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` and after `ssh-add -K`

Comment: And this approach really breaks my environment ((

Comment: Ho sorry I didn't know you had several install. Hope you recover easily.

Comment: After a few hours of trying to hack this out, your solution works. Thanks so much!